# Worklight jsonstore , keeping track of last collection date - how to do that

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

we support disconnected mobile application , some of the data we store locally and update when it is necessary , we would like to keep track and show to the user when we updated jsonstore data with date and time , is there a api on json store which can give us this info , when each collections was last updated with date and time etc.

Answer (score 3):

There is not an API to give this information, you could use the enhance function to write your own wrappers to track when you make modifications.